# If a company in China says it accepts Visa, does it accept all Visas?

Tags: credit-card, visa

I am doing some finance research for payment methods in China, there is some confusion as to whether only certain types of Visa Credit Cards are accepted at businesses versus all Visas...

Is this the case? Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: I cannot speak for China, but even in North America various types of plastic, all with the Visa logo, can be accepted or rejected. Debit/prepaid cards typically have smaller swipe fees when run as such, so some companies here accept *only* these types. In addition, Visa and MasterCard are nearly universal here, but in China the market's pretty much in the hands of one giant card issuer, and Visa/MasterCard acceptance is as spotty as Discover or Diner's Club.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, **credit** card networks (as opposed to debit/ATM cards that may or may not have Visa/MC logos) have a rule that a merchant must accept any **credit** card with their logo. Visa [rules for merchants in the US](http://usa.visa.com/download/merchants/card-acceptance-guidelines-for-visa-merchants.pdf) say it explicitly:

> Accept all types of valid Visa cards. Although Visa card acceptance
>   rules may vary based on country specific requirements or local
>   regulations, to offer the broadest possible range of payment options
>   to cardholder customers, most merchants choose to accept all
>   categories of Visa debit, credit, and prepaid cards.*

Unfortunately the Visa site for China is in Chinese, so I can't find similar reference there. You can complain against a merchant who you think had violated Visa rules [here](https://usa.visa.com/checkoutfees/contact.jsp).

That said, its not a law, its a contract between the merchant processor and the Visa International organization, and merchants are known to break these rules here and there (most commonly - refusing to accept foreign cards, including in the US). Also, local laws may affect these contracts (for example, in the US it is legal to set minimum amount requirements when accepting credit cards).

This only affects **credit** card processing, and merchants that don't accept **credit** cards may still accept **debit** cards since those work in different networks, under a different set of rules. Those who accept credit cards, are also required to accept debit cards (at least if used as credit).

Comment: Tell that to Sam's Club or Aldi Food Stores; they accept debit cards but not credit in the name of "loss prevention" and "cost savings".

Comment: @KeithS debit cards have nothing to do with this. Entirely different system.

Comment: They're Visa-branded cards; however, the rules document has a footnote: "Visa debit and credit cards may have different acceptance policies if you are located in the U .S ., Australia, or Canada" which covers the idiosyncracies I've seen. I guess in China, if they want to accept Visa they have to take *any* Visa.

Comment: @KeithS I think that is because ATM-like POSes are only used in these countries. In EU they have a pin&chip system for credit cards, and most of the world adheres to the more secure EU standard, not the retarded US way of doing things.

Comment: It's not a different network; that's why Visa brands these cards in the first place (otherwise you'd be using a network like Cirrus, built around ATMs). The transaction goes to Visa as the clearinghouse and they forward it to the issuing bank, which deals with it based on the exact type of card. The only change at POS is that the card reader can tell based on data from the stripe (maybe even a function of the card number) that it is a debit card and thus to show the PIN screen; older readers don't even do that.

Comment: @KeithS you're wrong. ATM purchases don't go through Visa. If you're using your PIN - it goes through ATM network (like Cirrus), not Visa. If you're signing - *then* it goes through Visa, and is treated as a credit-card transaction. POS that doesn't support ATM networks just treats debit cards as if they were credit cards (and that's how US debit cards are treated everywhere in the world).

Comment: @littleadv - **pin&chip system for credit cards**. You bet it was so secure(I live in UK though). It can be bypassed very easily. A guy did a Masters paper, in UK, on how easy it was to break this system. It isn't any better than the US one. The banks then sued the professor and the student for promoting forgery and putting it in the public domain, rather than accepting their system was faulty.

Comment: @DumbCoder link? Cryptoanalysis is always fun to read:) But the question is how easy it is to break for a layman. 3DES is not secure. But will an average petty thief bother trying to break your encryption of your personal information on a flash drive he found? Most likely not, he'll just sell it somewhere. American cards are *only* magnetic. The ease with which they can be stolen and forged without anyone noticing is astounding. Pin&chip may not be 100% secure, but how easy it is to forge it? Don't know.

Comment: @littleadv http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/banking/nopin/press-release.html

Comment: @DumbCoder very good read! MIM attack, how nice:) But note that you have to use a genuine card for that (i.e.: stolen card, not forged), which although still doable, provides a difficulty for the criminal (stolen cards get noticed faster and cancelled quicker than forged). I hope they've dealt with the breach by now, but it does require re-issue of cards and updating software on terminals, so they might have not yet. But that's a good paper to cite if your card is stolen and then used and the bank refuses to pay!

Answer (score 1):

Many businesses that accept regular VISA credit cards will not accept VISA purchase cards intended for corporate/gov purchasing departments and able to furnish a more detailed audit trail (purchase order #, lot #, etc.) than a regular credit card.  Other merchants take ONLY VISA purchase cards.